# корзина jQuery добавление товара

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Нужно сделать так чтобы когда в корзине появлялся товар было написано "оформить заказ" , вместо "корзина пуста"

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.header__menu a i').click(function() {
    $('.sub-menu').toggle()
  })

  //тут кол-во товара
  $('.add-tovar').click(function() {
    $("#tovar").text(parseInt($("#tovar").text()) + 1);
  })

  //тут должна прибавляться цена товара
  $('.add-tovar').click(function() {
    // Get total 
    var total = $('#cena').attr('data-total-price')
    // Set total converting it to number 
    total = +$(".cost", this).attr('data-price') + (+total)
    $('#cena').attr('data-total-price', total)
    //----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Set price veiw
    $("#cena").text('$' + total);

  })
  // тут нужно сделать так чтобы #kol(корзина пуста) становился hide или 
  //  display:none, а новый селектор с надписью "оформить заказ появлялся"
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bassket">
  <p>
    Товаров:<span id="tovar">0</span> Цена:
    <span id="cena" data-total-price="0">0</span>

  </p>

  <i class="fas fa-shopping-basket"></i>
  <span id="kol">корзина пуста</span>

</div>
```

Comment: Используй просто плагин https://github.com/rah-emil/angry-cart.js. На чистом JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.add-tovar').click(function() {
  var count = parseInt($("#tovar").text()) + 1;
  $("#tovar").text(count);
  $("#kol").text((count > 0)? "оформить заказ" : "корзина пуста");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.header__menu a i').click(function() {
    $('.sub-menu').toggle()
  })

  //тут кол-во товара
  $('.add-tovar').click(function() {
    $("#tovar").text(parseInt($("#tovar").text()) + 1);
  })

  //тут должна прибавляться цена товара
  $('.add-tovar').click(function() {
    // Get total 
    var total = $('#cena').attr('data-total-price')
    // Set total converting it to number 
    total = +$(".cost", this).attr('data-price') + (+total)
    $('#cena').attr('data-total-price', total)
    //----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Set price veiw
    $("#cena").text('$' + total);

    // тут нужно сделать так чтобы #kol(корзина пуста) становился hide или 
    //  display:none, а новый селектор с надписью "оформить заказ появлялся"
    // На добавление товара будет проверка 
    $('#kol').text((+$('#tovar').text()) > 0 ? 'оформить заказ' : 'корзина пуста');

  })

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bassket">
  <p>
    Товаров:<span id="tovar">0</span> Цена:
    <span id="cena" data-total-price="0">0</span>

  </p>

  <i class="fas fa-shopping-basket"></i>
  <span id="kol">корзина пуста</span>

</div>
```